# Selecting related model: Left join, prefetch_related or select_related?

Tags: sql, django

Considering I have the following relationships:

```
class House(Model):
  name = ...

class User(Model):
  """The standard auth model"""
  pass

class Alert(Model):
  user = ForeignKey(User)
  house = ForeignKey(House)
  somevalue = IntegerField()

  Meta:
    unique_together = (('user', 'property'),)
```

In one query, I would like to get the list of houses, and whether the current user has any alert for any of them.

In SQL I would do it like this:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM house h
LEFT JOIN alert a
       ON h.id = a.house_id
    WHERE a.user_id = ?
       OR a.user_id IS NULL
```

And I've found that I could use `prefetch_related` to achieve something like this:

```
p = Prefetch('alert_set', queryset=Alert.objects.filter(user=self.request.user), to_attr='user_alert')
houses = House.objects.order_by('name').prefetch_related(p)
```

The above example works, but `houses.user_alert` is a list, not an `Alert` object. I only have one alert per user per house, so what is the best way for me to get this information?

`select_related` didn't seem to work. Oh, and surely I know I can manage this in multiple queries, but I'd really want to have it done in one, and the 'Django way'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is clearer if you start with the multiple query approach, and then try to optimise it. To get the `user_alerts` for every house, you could do the following:

```
houses = House.objects.order_by('name')
for house in houses:
    user_alerts = house.alert_set.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

The `user_alerts` queryset will cause an extra query for every house in the queryset. You can avoid this with `prefetch_related`.

```
alerts_queryset = Alert.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
houses = House.objects.order_by('name').prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('alert_set', queryset=alerts_queryset, to_attrs='user_alerts'),
)
for house in houses:
    user_alerts = house.user_alerts
```

This will take two queries, one for houses and one for the alerts. I don't think you require select related here to fetch the user, since you already have access to the user with `self.request.user`. If you want you could add `select_related` to the `alerts_queryset`:

```
alerts_queryset = Alert.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).select_related('user')
```

In your case, `user_alerts` will be an empty list or a list with one item, because of your `unique_together` constraint. If you can't handle the list, you could loop through the queryset once, and set `house.user_alert`:

```
for house in houses:
    house.user_alert = house.user_alerts[0] if house.user_alerts else None
```

Comment: Thanks, I think there are a few typos in your code... though I managed to get it working. That doesn't fix the issue where I get a list, a not a single item though. Do you think we could get `user_alerts` to be an `Alert` object?

Comment: I haven't run the code, so I'm happy to accept any [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43342718/edit) to fix typos. No, I don't know any way to tell Django to make `user_alerts` an object rather than a list. If you really need the object, then loop through the queryset once and set `house.user_alert` as I suggested at the end of the answer.

Comment: I figured I could also do `user_alerts.first()`, but that would be cleaner without that.

Comment: Actually it doesn't. `user_alerts` is a list.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as the right answer, althought it doesn't solve the problem of extracting a single row, but it confirms that I was on the right track. Thanks.